# openssl s_client TLS connection through proxy with clientAuth

Tags: http, ssl, https, proxy, openssl

I'd like to use `openssl s_client` to open a TLS connection through a proxy (Squid) to an origin server using the CONNECT request method. I am using a client certificate to connect to the proxy server as shown:

> `openssl s_client -connect my_proxy:4443 -CAfile /etc/ssl/ca/ca.crt -cert /etc/ssl/cert/client.crt -key /etc/ssl/key/client_key.pem`

After running the above, connection information prints out fine and then I enter the CONNECT and GET methods, and this works fine:

> `CONNECT www.google.com:80 HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.google.com`
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
>
> `GET /search?q=ip+address HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.google.com`
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

However, I would really like to be able to establish a TLS (https) connection but I haven't been able to get it to work:

> `CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.google.com`
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
>
> `GET /search?q=ip+address HTTP/1.1`
>
> closed

What am I doing wrong here? Before you say to try OpenSSL 1.1.x which has the -proxy parameter, I've already tried that. Note that the CA cert, client cert and client key on the above command are for the connection to my proxy server, not for the target server (google.com), as shown below with OpenSSL 1.1.0-pre3 (same output if I try to connect to google:443).

> `openssl s_client -connect google.com:80 -proxy my_proxy:4443 -CAfile /etc/ssl/ca/ca.crt -cert /etc/ssl/cert/client.crt -key /etc/ssl/key/client_key.pem`
>
> CONNECTED(00000003)
>
> s_client: HTTP CONNECT failed
>
> no peer certificate available
>
> No client certificate CA names sent
>   SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 25 bytes
>   Verification: OK
>
> New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
>   Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
>   Compression: NONE
>   Expansion: NONE
>   No ALPN negotiated

I was able to load my client cert, client key, and CA cert into Firefox (all bundled in a pkcs12 file) and am able to connect to various websites through TLS. This should be possible on the command line.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the CA cert, client cert and client key on the above command are for the connection to the proxy server, not for the -connect server."

I doubt that. According to the source `-proxy` is only used to make the tunnel through the proxy, i.e.

- makes a TCP connect to the given proxy
- sends the CONNECT request with the target from `-connect` argument to the proxy
- waits for the response of the proxy that the tunnel got established
- no certificates are involved when creating the tunnel, like it should be

> This should be possible on the command line.

This is only possible with the `-proxy` option. Version of `s_client` which don't have this option yet can not be used alone to establish an connection through a HTTP proxy because the necessary functionality is simply not implemented. You might try to use `s_client` together with other tools which will provide the necessary tunnel, like [socat](http://blog.chmd.fr/ssh-over-ssl-episode-2-replacing-proxytunnel-with-socat.html) or [proxytunnel](http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net/intro.php).

Comment: I've edited the question to show output with the `-proxy` option. My certs are for connecting to my proxy, not to google.com. The only authentication proxytunnel seems to support is user:pass and NTLM. I will take a look and see if what I'm going for can be done with socat.

Comment: @vic: my guess is that the proxy itself requires SSL(i.e. proxy is set to `https://my_proxy:4433` and not the more common `http://my_proxy:4433`), because otherwise the direct `s_client` to the proxy would not have succeeded. But proxies which require SSL themselves are not supported by the `-proxy` parameter and they are not supported by most other software which makes use of HTTP proxies.